# Between two tags remove space in display: inline-block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little bit confusing for `display:inline-block` once I have use inline-block shown in little space in two tags. When I use `float: left` it's working fine.

Any Idea why coming space in `inline-block`.

[image]

```css
.main {
  padding-top:40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="main">
  <span class="btn btn-primary">Primary</span>
  <span class="btn btn-success">Success</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is like this:

```css
.main {
  padding-top:40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="main">
  <span class="btn btn-primary">Primary</span><span class="btn btn-success">Success</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand this question, can you remove your answer...? I need to delete this question...